# Unexpected token ' when generating a png chart using node-export-server

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, highcharts, cmd

I am trying to export a highchart graph using the node-export-server library;

`npm install highcharts-export-server -g`

**Library and tutorial:**

> https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server#server-test

Like in the documentation at Github I started the server using `highcharts-export-server --enableServer 1` and with another cmd window I tried to run the following command:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"infile":{"title": "text": "Steep Chart"}, "xAxis": {"categories": ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar"]}, series": [{"data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}}' 127.0.0.1:7801 -o mychart.png
```

Running this gives the error of the unexpected token `'` or `&#39;`. This error pops up at the terminal in which the command is executed. Changing `'` into `"` and vice versa does help at this side. No error pops up and the command seems to work:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  1273  100  1137  100   136  71062   8500 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 71062
```

An image called `mychart.png` has been generated, but cannot be opened.

At the server side, the following error is presented:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at parse (C:\Users\Maarten Courtin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\highcharts-export-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:88:17)
    at C:\Users\Maarten Courtin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\highcharts-export-server\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:116:18
    at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Maarten Courtin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\highcharts-export-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:262:16)
    at done (C:\Users\Maarten Courtin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\highcharts-export-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:251:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Maarten Courtin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\highcharts-export-server\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:307:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:106:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
```

Does anybody know what the solution is for this problem?

Comment: Is the command in multiple lines? If so, you need to end each line with backslash (\\).

Comment: It is not. I just mentioned it in multiple line for clarity, but that might not have worked.. Good question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is at Window Command Prompt. Unix shell and Windows Command Prompt doesn't treat quotes identically. The command that you are using will work on Unix but not on Windows.

For fixing this, you have to use double quotes with escape character, like below

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"infile\":{\"title\": {\"text\": \"Steep Chart\"}, \"xAxis\": {\"categories\": [\"Jan\", \"Feb\", \"Mar\"]}, \"series\": [{\"data\": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4]}]}}" 127.0.0.1:7801 -o mychart.png
```

I haven't tested above command, there can be some quotes missing here and there, but I guess you got the idea.

**Invalid JSON** : Please note that the JSON that you are posting is invalid. Check it [here](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).